# How to deal with C# memory allocation (Address space fragmentation)

Tags: c#, c#-4.0, memory, memory-management, out-of-memory

I am running into the following problem. Using C# (and XNA), I try to allocate an array of moderate size (~55 MB) of type Color[]. Color is 4 bytes. However, 90% percent of the memory allocation tries fail due to an "Out of memory" exception despite the system having 16 GB RAM (~12 GB free).

I am already using the MemoryFailPoint class to reserve the memory (see code below) but this seems to not help. I assume I am running into 'address fragmentation' issues. But what can I do about it? Is there a way to 'defragment' the address space?

```
    public static bool AllocateMemory(out Color[] colorBuffer, int size)
    {
        // Color has 4 bytes
        int sizeInMegabytes = (int)Math.Ceiling(((float)(size * 4) / (1024f * 1024f)));

        #region Use MemoryFailPoint class to reserve memory

        // Check that we have enough memory to allocate the array.
        MemoryFailPoint memoryReservation = null;
        try
        {
            memoryReservation =
                new MemoryFailPoint(sizeInMegabytes);
        }
        catch (InsufficientMemoryException ex)
        {
            colorBuffer = null;

            Warning.Happened("Failed to reserve " + sizeInMegabytes + " MB memory.");

            return false;
        }

        #endregion

        // Allocte memory for array
        colorBuffer = new Color[size];

        //Now that we have allocated the memory we can go ahead and call dispose
        memoryReservation.Dispose();

        return true;
    }
```

Comment: This usually happens with 32-bit applications. Are you compiling for 32-bit target? Any possibility to make it 64-bit only?

Comment: The question is too broad, especially lacking a good [mcve]. I do notice that you are failing to dispose of your `memoryReservation` object on an exception. Without a good MCVE, it's impossible to know whether that's related to your observed problem or not. You may well be running into fragmentation issues; in particular, the array is likely allocated in the large-object heap, which is not always compacted (check `GCSettings.LargeObjectHeapCompactionMode`), which can lead to allocation failures due to fragmentation. Improve your question if you want a useful answer.

Comment: Unfortunately, making it 64 Bit is not an option.

Answer (score 0):

This is a frequent issue, specially in 32-bit platforms. I suggest to use some kind of fragmented or "chunked" array class, like this one:

https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/joshwil/2005/08/10/bigarrayt-getting-around-the-2gb-array-size-limit/

Of course there will be a loss of performance. However, it depends on your specific application and how frequently you access that array.